# Keep changes to an object temporary during method chaining

Tags: python, class, oop, fluent, fluent-interface

I am designing an object-oriented data structure that shall be simple to handle from the user's perspective, e.g., by method chaining (aka [Fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)). However, each change should only act *temporarily* on the object: within that chain, but not beyond that chain.
Here is a simplified example that does *not* work as intended:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.sum = num

    def add(self, num=0):
        self.sum += num
        return self

number = C(23)
number.add(7).add(12).sum
# 42
number.sum
# 42 (but I expect: 23)
```

In this case, `.add()` makes *permanent* changes to `number`. However, permanent changes should only be possible like this:

```
# This is the only way how a user should make permanent changes:
number = number.add(4).add(12)
```

In the *temporary* scope, I am looking for a way to get back to the old version of `number` after the chain is terminated. On the edge of despair, I can think of ugly solutions like "instance replication":

```
class C2:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.sum = num

    def add(self, num=0):
        self2 = C2(self.sum) # or equivalently: self2 = copy.deepcopy(self)
        self2.sum += num
        return self2

number = C2(23)
number.add(7).add(12).sum
# 42
number.sum
# 23
```

However, the actuall classes and objects with which I am working contain a huge amount of data, attributes, methods, and even subclasses. So we should avoid copying the instance in every single method, besides the fact that it involves ugly code.

Are there ways to solve this problem, e.g. by (silently) creating a single copy only once at the first element of the chain? Or by destroying any changes made at the end of the chain? *(Note that real-world "changes" involve many different, commutable methods other than just adding numbers)*

An accepted solution should perform the necessary operations *internally*, i.e., without bothering the user interface:

```
# These are NOT accepted solutions:
number.copy().add(4).add(12)
number.add(4).add(12).undo()
```

If there no direct solution other than self-replication, the question would be: What is the most elegant way to do it that sustains code-readability and keeps memory usage low? E.g., decorating every class method by self-replicating function?

Comment: I don't see how it would be possible for the object to automagically detect the end of the "temporary scope" - except possibly by writing your own python-based language and even then... FWIW, all "fluent interface" implementations I've seen so far either mutate the object in place or return a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of modyfing the object on which you call the method, return a modified copy:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.sum = num

    def add(self, num=0):
        return C(self.sum + num)

number = C(23)
assert number.add(7).add(12).sum == 42
assert number.sum == 23
```

For details on memory handling in this solution, see comments of this posts. This solution is standard way of solving your problem.

Comment: Then I'm telling you that this is standard practice, not a dirty hack.

Comment: I know that it is standard for many appliations. But is it also the recommended (or only) strategy for large-size instances? I am afraid it would dramatically increase memory usage :S Or does python automatically remove all instances when the chain terminates?

Comment: The intermediate instances will be removed from memory as soon as they won't be reachable. For example, when we're done with calling ...add(12), the result (instance with sum==42) has a reference that will be used to fetch it's sum attribute, but result of number.add(7) won't be reachable anymore, so it's gonna be subject for garbage collection.

Comment: This doesn't mean that it's gonna be removed from memory at this exact time - there is no guarantee that GC will run, but at this point it's marked as obsolete. In the long run the intermediate chaining results will be discarded and will pollute memory only for a short time.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science) ; http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Python_Garbage_Collection ; http://arctrix.com/nas/python/gc/ and of course try googling yourself. If you need more explanations, let me know, I'll try to help you.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanations, it deserves the +1. Anyway, I can not be sure whether traces of my instances will remain, as the classes and subclasses are very complex and contain lots of pointers. Probably GC is a good start to monitor what's happening.